# .NET fiddle/Visual Studio: Different results for regex replace on invalid XML character

Tags: c#, xml, regex, .net-fiddle

I'm trying to filter invalid characters from an XML file, and have the following test project;

```
class Program
{
    private static Regex _invalidXMLChars = new Regex(@"(?<![\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\uFEFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = "assd&#xF;abv";

        Console.WriteLine(_invalidXMLChars.IsMatch(text));
    }
}
```

This test project outputs the expected result (True) with [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pD0zSv);

But when I try to implement the same code in my project, the invalid characters are not found and outputs "False".

How come this works in .NET fiddle, but not in my project?

**Altering the source XML file is not an option**

Comment: over 50% of the time I've seen people ask questions like this, it's because they've forgotten to use the post-replacement string at some later point. E.g. `string dirty = xxx; var clean = regex.Replace(dirty,""); ...; doSomething = ParseXml(dirty);` But since you've not shown your actual code that exhibits your problem, it's not possible to be sure.

Comment: The test project that I have in .NET fiddle is the exact same that I have in Visual Studio, but it yields different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is right. None of the characters `&`, `#`, `x`, `F` or `;` are part of your Regex. However, in HTML `&#xF;` translates to the C# pendant `\u000f` which then is replaced due to the Regex definition `\0xE-\0x1F`.

Using `\u000f` in Visual Studio gives a match:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    private static Regex _invalidXMLChars = new Regex(@"(?<![\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\uFEFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "assd\u000fabv";
        Console.WriteLine(_invalidXMLChars.IsMatch(text));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression does not apply because the string contains the escaped sequence that will render the "illegal" character later.

To filter this out, you will have to unescape the string before testing the regular expression:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("assd&#xF;abv");

    Console.WriteLine(_invalidXMLChars.IsMatch(text));
}
```

A second option would be to use the regular expression to match the escape sequence instead:

```
var text2 = "assd&#xF;abv";
var rx = new Regex(@"&#x[0-9A-F];");
Console.WriteLine(rx.IsMatch(text2));
```

Hope this helps!